# Как задать значение?

Tags: pascal

Не получается задать значение, помогите, пожалуйста.

```
program ggwp;

var a,b,c,d,e,g: real;
begin 
readln(a);
b:= write('asdasdsa',b);
c:= write('ggwp');
d:= write('asdasd12123123');
if a= 0 then 
writeln(b);
if a>0 then
writeln(c);
if d<0 then
writeln(d);
end.
```

Comment: Отформатируйте свой код (специальная кнопочка есть рядом).

Comment: что код делать-то должен? строки глупо сравнивать с числом. это не js/php.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу бросается в глаза очевидная ошибка - вы зачем-то пытаетесь получить от процедуры write возвращаемое значение, тогда как это процедура, а не функция.